# how to post-convert all strings getters within package?

Tags: java, spring, encoding, aop, dto

Assume i have java beans in **java package**

**com.mycompany.dto**

**In this package there are classes**. **Their strings have enconings** for example **win-1520**. When i will call get on their attributes, i would like to have them **encoded in utf-8 instead win-1250**.

I would like to create one class for this purpose and register somewhere(maybe package-info.java) and let it all proceed automatically.

Could you post here a snippet how to configure spring application to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: an aspect should be a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how string encoding works in Java. Strings are encoding-independent (though they are stored internally as UTF16). You only need an encoding when you convert them into bytes.

So you probably have a different problem.

Comment: I solved this issue by adding folowing lines to hibernate config.
`<prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">utf8</prop>`
Thanks anyway